# open wire detection of open drain output

Tags: wire, detection

[image]

I am working with a commercial dc  motor speed controller it has a open drain output which can be used for generating fault signals , i am taking that output to a pcb through wire , i am giving it a pullup to use the open drain output as logic level output .whenever there is fault the mosfet is on and the output is low ,when there is no fault the mosfet is off and output is pulled high. i want to make circuit to detect if there is disconnection between open drain output and the pcb_wire_connector and also give logic level fault signals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: -

[image]

It uses a window comparator and, under normal operation the voltage into the window comparator is \$\frac{2.2}{3.2}\times V_{CC}\$ and, when the MOSFET operates that voltage gets close to 0 volts but, importantly, if the wire link is broken, the voltage sensed by the window comparator is close to \$V_{CC}\$ thus indicating a wire open fault: -

[image]

- INPUT is the voltage level on the wire
- VrefHi for a Vcc of 5 volts would be about 3.5 to 4 volts
- VrefLo for a Vcc of 5 volts would be about 2 to 3 volts

You can mount the 2K2 resistor on the output terminal block of the motor controller module in parallel with the wiring that goes to your PCB.

Comment: what should be vrefHi,INPUT,Vreflo ?

Comment: @powermachines INPUT is the voltage signal on the wire. If Vcc is 5 volts then VrefHi would be a bit greater than \$\frac{5\times 2.2}{3.2}\$ or about 3.5 to 4 volts. VrefLo would be a bit less than \$\frac{5\times 2.2}{3.2}\$ or about 2 to 3 volts. There is scope to set the reference voltages across a range of values for this to work. If the LED lights then there is either a controller fault or a wiring fault.

Comment: sir,motorcontroller is and OEM product so cannot add the resistor across the mosfet ,i can only make changes on pcb, is there any other way .thank you for response

Comment: You can mount a 2k2 resistor across the terminals where you put in the wires to the OEM product surely? This sort of trick is done all the time - crimp the resistor ends to a suitable mounting lug and you're good to go.

Comment: i am not clear regarding the crimping of resistor of across the mosfet of open drain output

Comment: @powermachines the OEM equipment has screw terminals for wiring to your PCB yes? And you can probably put a wire and a resistor into the same screw terminal yes? Maybe something like this: https://workforce.libretexts.org/@api/deki/files/3753/05099.png?revision=1. And you could put ferrules on the resistor like this: https://hackaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/ferrules-e1522206526373_bright.png?w=800?

Comment: thank you Andy aka

Comment: If I were you I'd wait a day until formally accepting my answer in case anyone comes along with a better proposal @powermachines.

Comment: i am waiting for more answers